# Cocos2d access scene properties and methods

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm trying to include a pause feature for my game. So far running `pause` on the `[CCDirector sharedDirector]` has been good enough when run through my `pauseGame` method (which incorporates a BOOL to tell if game is paused, etc.)

However, I noticed that if I go back to the homescreen on my device, my application delegate will automatically run `pause` and `resume` on the `sharedDirector`.

Ideally, I would like access my active scene/layer's so I can run my own pause method.

How can I: 1) check if the current scene is my game scene
2) access the game scene's pause property, and run the pauseGame method on it?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The running scene is `[CCDirector sharedDirector].runningScene`

If you call [scene pauseSchedulerAndActions]; on the current scene this is will not be resumed when going back and forth on the home screen.

If you need to pause ALL nodes in the hierarchy, here is a method to extend CCNode

```
-(void)recursivePauseSchedulerAndActions {
    [self pauseSchedulerAndActions];
    CCNode *child;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, child) {
        [child recursivePauseSchedulerAndActions];
    }
}
-(void)recursiveResumeSchedulerAndActions {
    [self resumeSchedulerAndActions];
    CCNode *child;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, child) {
        [child recursiveResumeSchedulerAndActions];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. An issue I have with the pause or pauseSchedulerWithActions is that I have sprites on the screen that implement touch. So while the game is paused, you can still drag them around. This is why I tried using my own pause method in game, which removes the touchdelegates and re-adds them. That's why I'd prefer to use my own method within the class. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a different approach for pausing a game.

I usually have a game scene with game layers. To pause the game I add a new layer (covering the entire screen) and when I pause the game I display this layer. This way you can stop touching events for the game layer and restore them when resuming the game (and removing the pause layer from the scene)